# Finding the probability and mean for binary logistic regression

Tags: probability, logistic, categorical-data, mean, binary-data

I want to derive the logit model so that I can calculate the probability of the sample choose $Y=1$ and $Y=0$.  I've read [somewhere](http://www.brynmawr.edu/socialwork/GSSW/Vartanian/Handouts/Logistic.Prob2.PD) that after obtaining the regression (e.g. XB=b0+b1x+b2x) we can use the mean of each variable (x's value) to derive XB.  But SPSS logistic regression doesn't provide the mean for each of the variable.  So my question is

1. Can we use the mean of each variable that we derived from
   descriptive statistic (i.e. analyze -> descriptive statistic ->
   descriptive)?
2. If no. 1 is correct, how can I calculate the mean for the
       categorical variable of more than 2 (e.g. single, married, divorced
       and widowed), as the mean does not provide mean for each categories?

Comment: What do you mean by "mean of the variable"? What "mean from the descriptive statistic" do you want to use and what for? Logistic regression does not calculate means of variables...

Comment: I want to derive the logit model so that I could calculate the probability of the sample choose Y=1 and Y=0. I've read somewhere that after obtaining the regression (e.g. XB=b0+b1x+b2x) we can use the mean of each variable (x's value) to derive XB.  But spss logistic regression doesn't provide the mean for each of the variable.  so my question is can we use the mean of each variable that we derived from descriptive statistic?

Comment: Could you provide a direct quote of what exactly have you read and where? It is unclear what do you mean and I am afraid that in this form your question is unanswerable.

Comment: This approach is invalid, because the link function is nonlinear.  Except in very special circumstances, the probability evaluated at the point of mean values of the regressors will *not* equal the mean probability.  The two values can be very different especially when the mean probability is far from 50%. After looking through some recent handouts on regression by the same professor I would recommend you find another source of information about statistical concepts and techniques.

Comment: The link in the post does't work anymore ...

Comment: http://www.brynmawr.edu/socialwork/GSSW/Vartanian/Handouts/Logistic.Prob2.PDF